# Using RunningObjectTable alongside WPF WebBrowser

Tags: wpf, vbscript, com, com-interop

We are hosting a 3rd party web page in a WPF WebBrowser control. The 3rd party web site uses a VBScript `GetObject(, "Prog.Id")` call to get access to an already instantiated object.

I am aware this is a silly idea so please don't just answer telling me that. We need to integrate with this site and they are not in a position to change their VBScript approach.

Using PInvoke I can call RegisterActiveObject and GetActiveObject from within my WPF app code.

```
[DllImport("oleaut32.dll")]
public static extern int RegisterActiveObject([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object punk, ref Guid rclsid, uint dwFlags, out int pdwRegister);

[DllImport("oleaut32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.None, ExactSpelling = false)]
public static extern void GetActiveObject(ref Guid rclsid, IntPtr pvReserved, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out Object ppunk);
```

If I use GetObject in the WPF code after RegisterActiveObject I get the previously instantiated version but the VBScript running in the WebBrowser control cannot see the running instance

This is the code to Register an instance with the ROT

```
int regResult = RegisterActiveObject(gatewayObject, ref gatewayClsIdGuid, 0, out this.objectRegisterValue);
```

The VBScript GetObject call that is not seeing the registered instance is

```
If (existing = True) Then
    MsgBox("Getting not creating")
    Set objTest = GetObject(, progId)
Else
    Set objTest = CreateObject(progId)
End if

On Error Goto 0
If (objTest Is Nothing) Then
    MsgBox("Unable to get object")
Else
    MsgBox("Got the object successfully")
End If
```

Why is the `GetObject(, progId)` call returning `Nothing`?

Comment: Perhaps you need to pass 1 for the flags since that's ROTFLAGS_ALLOWANYCLIENT ?

Comment: Just tried that but the GetObject still results in Nothing